# Choosing 5 of 7 balls of different colors

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> How many ways we can order 5 out of 7 balls, where 4 are blue, 1 is
>   white, 1 is red and 1 is green. We can assume that all blue balls are
>   the same (their order don't matter), while the overall order of the
>   balls matter.

My solution is  $ 4*4*4*4*3*2 $ , however that's not correct. The correct answer is 135. Could someone explain the approach to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your formula?  That way, we can show what went wrong. You'll probably learn more from that than us just giving the right formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the following combinations:

1) 3 blue , 1 red , 1 white

This can be arranged in 5!/3! = 20 ways.
We divide the total arrangement by the total arrangement of the indistinguishable balls because we need to negate the double counting of them. In this case it was the 3 indistinguishable blue balls.

2) 3 blue, 1 red, 1 green in 20 ways.

3) 3 blue, 1 white, 1 green in 20 ways.

4) 2 blue, 1 white, 1 green and 1 red in 5!/2! ways

5) 4 blue and 1 (either red, white or green) in 5 ways each.

So the total is 135 ways.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this:

1. Use $4$ blue balls. So now you have one of the other colors: $3$ possibilities for that color, and $5$ possible locations for that $1$ non-blue ball gives $3 \cdot 5=15$ possibilities
2. Use $3$ blue balls. So now you have $3$ options for those $2$ colors, $5$ options for the location for the first of those two, and then $4$ options for the location of the other: $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4=60$ possibilities
3. Use $2$ blue balls. Now you have $5$ options for the location of the first of the non-blue balls, $4$ for the next, and $3$ for the last: $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5=60$ possibilities

Total: $15+60+60=135$ possibilities

Comment: Neatly presented!

Comment: @Allawonder Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, let us see how can we have the combination of 5 balls:

> 2 blue balls(case A)
>   Number of ways=Selecting 3 balls from available 3 balls=$$\binom{3}{3}=1$$
>   3 blue balls(case B)
>   Number of ways=Selecting 2 balls from available 3 balls=$$\binom{2}{3}=3$$
>   4 blue balls(case C)
>   Number of ways=Selecting 1 ball from available 3 balls=$$\binom{1}{3}=3$$

For the first case, think of ball as numbers i.e. 5 numbers with 2 repeated , 
Arrangement=$$\frac{5!}{2!}=60$$

For the second casei.e. 5 numbers with 3 same repeated ,

Arrangement=$$\frac{5!}{3!}=20$$

For the third casei.e. 5 numbers with 4 same repeated ,

Arrangement=$$\frac{5!}{4!}=5$$

Answer=$$1*60+3*20+3*5=135$$